# In Hibernate 3.5, what are the annotation equivalents of constrained and outer-join?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations, jpa-annotations

I'm currently working to convert an application from using hibernate mapping files `(.hbm.xml)` to `hibernate/jpa` annotations (with a jpa annotation preference).

I am running into these two attributes in some of the hibernate mapping files on one-to-one relationships:

```
constrained="true"|"false"
outer-join="true"|"false"
```

I have been heavily researching these two but I cannot find a straight answer.

It seems that `optional="true"|"false"` can handle the both of them, but it feels wrong to accept this as the answer without a reference from documentation or an official source.